# Best case analysis of recursive algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I was given the following question:

> Given the following algorithm:
>
> ```
> Function f1(a, b)
> // a: int
> // b: int
>
> if b == 0
>     return b
> else
>     return a + f1(a, b-1)
> ```
>
> Determine the best and worst case complexity for this algorithm

I answered with `O(n)` and `Ω(1)`

- As when `b -> ∞` and `a ∈ Z`, you decrease b by 1 each time (`T(n) = 1 + T(n-1)`) which implies a runtime of `O(n)`
- But when when `a -> ∞` and `b = 0`, you always return on the base case immediately, hence `Ω(1)`

---

But the answer was:

> `O(n)` and `Ω(n)`

Why is this so?

Is `n` assumed to be `b`, and `Ω(1)` is simply `Ω(n)` because `n = 0`?

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: when `b -> ∞` and `a ∈ Z`, complexitites will be `O(n)` and `Ω(1)`
Case 2: for `a -> ∞` and `b = 0`, complexities will be `O(1)` and `Ω(n)`

So considering both cases, the best case complexity is  `O(n)` and the worst case is `Ω(n)`

Answer (score 0):

There function will have `b` recursive calls regardless of value of `a`. So, `n` is assumed to be `b`. In both best case and worst case scenarios the time complexity is same.

Hence, the best case time complexity is `O(n)` and the worst case time complexity is `Ω(n)`